# "Software sources" crashes since I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I recently updated my PC from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. Now “Software sources” crashes when I try to open it directly from Unity or from Ubuntu Software Center → Software sources.

When I try to open “Update manager”, I get the following error message. Note that the internet connection WORKS!

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please, can somebody help me on this?

---

In addition, I get the following error when I use `software-properties-gtk` from the terminal:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 429, in record
    return Record(self._records.record)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 114: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed some PPA which isn't available for Quantal (I guess, because [its URL](http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources) doesn't exist). You should open your `sources.list` file and delete the line for that PPA, with the command `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.

The line may be something like:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu/ quantal main source
```

But I just guessed it, you should see if there's any line like that and delete it. Or, if you remember the name of that PPA, you could just remove it, with something like that (replace rye/ubuntuone-extras for PPA's name):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very appreciated.

OK I did some tests and changed the content of /etc/apt/sources.list. I also removed all the content of that file (only for test purpose). At every tests, I got the error:

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 429, in record return Record(self._records.record) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 114: invalid continuation byte

with "software-properties-gtk" and “Software sources” and then it crashed.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks again,

JS

Comment: Hi again, I progressed. I fixed the “Software sources” problem with this one “https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1053749”. Then I did what you recommend. Now I have problem with Update-manager with the following error:
“W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources 404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.” Note that …/rye/ ubuntuone-extras... is still there.